# How to better see selected Chrome (or any other app) instance using “cmd”+“`” on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, osx-yosemite

I’m new to Mac OS X and when you <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> the do <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> you can switch instances of that application (chrome in my use case).

However, when I do that I can barely see what window instance is selected.  Is there a better way to do this? It would be nice if there was a red or blue highlighting the window instance you have selected.

I know <kbd>F10</kbd> will bring up all instances as well but it would be nice to use the arrow keys or something that indicates which window has focus (i.e. red borer or something).

Comment: Focussed window has traffic lights, top left.

Comment: @Tetsujin, good call, just noticing that now. thx!